# Searchkick Failing on Travis CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, travis-ci, searchkick

I just integrated Searchkick on my Rails 4.1 app and my Travis CI build just failed. I solved the first failure by adding the elasticsearch service in my .travis.yml, but the command to "reindex" the model has to be done via a Rails console, and that is the failure with:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     RuntimeError:
       Index missing - run Item.reindex
```

So how do I index a model by issuing the "Model.reindex" in Travis CI?

Here is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0-p247
env:
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
services:
  - elasticsearch
script:
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rspec spec/
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'create database mbb_test'
  - psql -c 'create database mbb_test;' -U postgres
bundler_args: --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out I just had to add this to my test helper (in my case spec_helper.rb) so that the Item gets "reindex"-ed every test:

```
config.before(:each) do
  Item.reindex
end
```

**A BETTER VERSION**

```
config.before(:each, es: true) do
    if Item.searchkick_index.exists?
      Item.searchkick_index.delete
      Item.reindex
    end
  end
```

taken from:
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/pull/95

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do in index the database, try `rails runner "<your rails console command here>"` right after you migrate and setup the database.

Comment: `bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex:all` will get the job done

Comment: @AndrewKane you might want to add that as answer. bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex:all put in the `script:` section before `bundle exec rspec spec/` also works

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your .travis.yml

```
services:
 - elasticsearch
```

Source: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#elasticsearch.

Worked for me.